# CNC stepper motor driving CC vs CV

Tags: stepper-motor, constant-current, cnc

I am trying to design a small CNC maching for milling PCBs. I am using unipolar stepper motors driven by a microcontroller, but I am unsure of what tehnique to use to drive them.

I once read that driving a motor with constant current provides a constant torque and driving them with constant voltage provides a constant speed.

But, using constant current source seems more intuitive to me. Since its the current through a conductor that generates a magnetic field around it. Meaning if I drive them with a constant voltage there would be a rise in the strength of the magnetic field untill it reaches its maximum (**if** I am not switching with higher frequency) generated by the coil. And if I were to drive them with constant current, the coild would immediately generate the maximum strength of the magnetic field and I would be able to drive them with higher frequencies.

- Is my logic here flawed, where am I wrong?
- What tehnique is usually used in milling machines?
- Should I look out for maximum voltage/current rating of a motor when using constant current?

Comment: Constant current, generally able to resort to voltage many times the nameplate rating, which applies to steady state after the inductance ceases impeding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In milling machines constant current is used to drive stepper motors.

You want the maximum torque of your stepper motors when using them (in the cnc machine). To achieve this, you would thus use constant current.

However, you do also want a reasonable speed of your motors. Therefore the supply that delivers the current, should be capable of also giving high enough voltages. 
If your constant current source is supplied with e.g. a 5V voltage, the maximum voltage of you stepper motors can be 5V, which will not give them a lot of speed. 
When you use for example a 30V supply, your constant current circuit will limit the curent and therefore protect your motor from breaking and the voltage will deliver the speed you need.

The voltage rating is just given as a maximum for when te motor is **not** turning.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the following link

Basic design It is a unipolar (or 5-wire type) driver. The motor must have 5 or 6 wires (or 8), as 4-wire motors are only for bipolar and 4-WIRE MOTORS WILL NOT WORK WITH THIS BOARD. The constant current system is crude but simple, it relies on setting the base of the main transistors at a "set" level, then this causes a "set" voltage across the sense resistor Rs, ie maintains constant current. It does get some temp drift with large currents, but it's simple and accurate enough with the resistor values i've tested. It actually works quite well! The brain has control of which of the 4 transistors are ON, and sets 3 possible current levels, enough to do 6th stepping and give 1200 steps/rev with hardware alone. The software I have provided also will do pwm and give 18th stepping, which is 3600 steps/rev, almost stepless operation.

I have built these boards and they work well, quiet and accurate motion with no loss of steps

http://www.piclist.com/techref/io/stepper/linistep/lini_wks.htm